# SimpleHttpConnectionManager being used incorrectly

Tags: java, http, apache-commons

SimpleHttpConnectionManager being used incorrectly.  Be sure that HttpMethod.releaseConnection() is always called and that only one thread and/or method is using this connection manager at a time.

Does Anyone know why this error shows up and is causes the files I want to download or to fail and retry or to download uncompleted

Thank you !

Comment: More code/exception trace would help us understand your problem better.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure that you don't use SimpleHttpConnectionManager to create and use connections from multiple threads. The simple connection manager is not designed for it - it returns always the same connection, and this is not thread safe.

In a multi-threaded environment, use a different manager that uses a pool of connections. See [MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.html).

Comment: Thank you 

The code was giving it a default httpclient , which comes with a default simplehttpconnection , so I changed it and forced it to take a multithreadedhhttpconnectionmanager.

Answer (score 10):

Prefer to take no credit for this, but as per Eyal Schneider's answer, find more info on using MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager in [Vincent de Villers excellent blog](http://vincentdevillers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/httpclient-best-pratices.html).

Code snippet copied in case the link ever disappears:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
GetMethod httpget = new GetMethod("http://www.myhost.com/");
try {
    httpclient.executeMethod(httpget);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(
        httpget.getResponseBodyAsStream(), httpget.getResponseCharSet());
    // consume the response entity
} finally {
    httpget.releaseConnection();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this