# SimpleHttpConnectionManager being used incorrectly. in couchdb

Tags: java, sockets, gwt, connection, couchdb

I am getting the error giving below in couchDB with GWT,

```
Be sure that HttpMethod.releaseConnection() is always called and that only one thread and/or method is using this connection manager at a time.
```

I create couchdb session once like

```
static Session session = null;
public static Session Couchconnect(){
    if(session==null) {
        session = new Session("localhost", "5984");
    }
    return session;
}
```

and used in different greeting service methods.

```
public void abc(){
 Session session = Connection.Couchconnect();
.....................
} 

public void abc2(){
 Session session = Connection.Couchconnect();
.....................
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleHttpConnectionManager being used incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088568/simplehttpconnectionmanager-being-used-incorrectly)