# in couchdb SimpleHttpConnectionManager being used incorrectly?

Tags: java, gwt, couchdb

> Be sure that `HttpMethod.releaseConnection()` is always called and that only one thread and/or method is using this connection manager at a time.

I create couchdb session once like

```
static Session session = null;
public static Session Couchconnect(){
    if(session==null) {
        session = new Session("localhost", "5984");
    }
    return session;
}
```

and used in different greeting service methods.

```
public void abc(){
    Session session = Connection.Couchconnect();
    ...
} 

public void abc2(){
    Session session = Connection.Couchconnect();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleHttpConnectionManager being used incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088568/simplehttpconnectionmanager-being-used-incorrectly)